# OpenStack is a Service or Group of Softwares?

Tags: cloud, openstack

Openstack is a set of software which we can used to create a cloud ?
(Eg: Materials to build a building?)

OR

Openstack is a Cloud service like Azure or AWS where we can have and handle Data or network or machines?
(Eg: Building(already built) which gives rooms?)

I read that Rackspace and some other clouds are built based on Openstack . So Openstack is a set of software which we can used to create a cloud.Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Openstack is a platform on which you can create Azure or AWS services. 
**It's a abstraction level software.** Yes, it's a set of software. But it provides lots of customization.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, openstack is a cloud operating system.It has nothing to do with the creation of a cloud. After all cloud is an aggregation of resources(say network,storage) and Openstack sits over this resources and manages them (the way a normal operating system manages system resources).It had the ability to offer underlying Infrastructure as a Service(Iaas).

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack is a set of software to install on ubuntu 16.04, Redhat Linux and so on. If OpenStack is installed on any platform it acts as a cloud operating system. OpenStack manages a large number of networks.

Reference: [docs.openstack.org](http://docs.openstack.org)